# how to use bootstrap3 grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-frameworks

I have been using twitter bootstrap for a year, its the one of those things which -"just works" . With release of twitter bootstrap3 its become even better and awesome with its mobile first approach. But i am not able to understand how to use it properly with mobile first approach.

Earlier there was `.span*` and `.offset*` class but now there are `.col-xs-* .col-md-* .col-sm-* .col-lg-*` and `.col-xs-offset-* .col-md-offset-*` classes respectively. Even now 'it-just-works' using `.col-md-*` i want to know the right way to use all these classes so as to not just use them but use them correctly to get most out of bootstrap3.

Thanks.

Comment: you can go to [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) for learning.

Comment: I know how to use bootstrap my question is about various classes used by bootstrap3 for mobile first approach how to use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these links very helpful:

http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction

http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using Bootstrap 3 for web development, how I'm using the Grid system is,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">     <%--this for 9X3 grid--%>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">   <%--this for 6X6 inner grid--%>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my question about using bootstrap3 as mobile first approach

Comment: for Extra small devices Phones (<768px) u can use ".col-xs-" class instead of ".col-md-"

Comment: and for mobile first approach first use "col-xs-" class then user other ones, for example "<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">"

Comment: that depends on your need

Answer (score 0):

I found (a) Bootstrap's own documentation helpful here, but also a (b) lynda.com topic in migrating to Bootstrap 3. Specifically, see "Dealing with grid changes"

(a) http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

(b) http://www.lynda.com/course20/Bootstrap-tutorials/Bootstrap-3-New-Features-Migration/138156-2.html